# iteration based printing in php for each loop

Tags: php

Hi i am trying  to print only 'a' on first iteration of for each  loop and only 'b'  on second iteration and only 'c' on third iteration.

```
<?php foreach ($results['questions'] as $result) {
    echo "string";
}
```

Comment: hows your array construct ?

Comment: print your array result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have clarified the `$result[]` array, nor you have specified which thing to compare for having `a` or `b` or `c`. Anyhow it may be like:

```
foreach($results['questions'] as $result)
{
    if($result['question_no'] == 'a') 
    {
         echo 'a'; // or something else
    }
    else if($result['question_no'] == 'b')
    {
         echo 'b'; // or something else...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: so whats the point of using if else ? since the value itself has the desired value ??

Comment: as per the OP, the question was to iterate using either `a` or `b` or `c`, so each time one of the `if-else` is going to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have idea about your array so, i'm use this simple array. try this code, use counter and check your iteration.

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/uTsQH)**

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $data = ['a','b','c'];
    foreach($data as $val)
    {
      $i++;  
      if($i == 1)
      {
          echo $val; // print a
      }
      if($i == 2)
      {
          echo$val; // print b
      }
      if($i == 3)
      {
          echo $val; // print c
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of `$results` ?

Let's say it is as follows:

```
$results = ['a' => 'result of A', 
            'b' => 'result of B', 
            'c' => 'result of C'];
```

Use function [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get keys from your array `$results`:

```
$resultKeys = array_keys($results);
```

Then you just `echo` each key with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function:

```
foreach($results as $key){
  echo $key . PHP_EOL;;
}
```